# How to insert a word/text in front of every "string" in vim and remove quotation marks

Tags: regex, vim, macvim

I have strings like this in my file: `case field == "first_name" || field == "last_name"` and I'd like to remove the quotations marks and put the text `constants.` in front of all of them.

This is the end goal: `case field == constants.first_name || field == constants.last_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using search and replace, just run the following command:

```
%s/\("\)\([^"]\{-}\)\1/constants.\2/g
```

part by part:

```
% - In all lines
s - substitute
\("\)\([^"]\{-}\)\1 - part1 (find any string that is surronded by double-quotes)
constants.\2 - by part2 (add constants. to second cached group in regex)
g - globally
```

Comment: this is awesome! thanks. i was doing it by hand, and then i started using `%s/"//g` to get rid of the quotes, and i realized there had to be a much better way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a macro.
Press `qaq` to empty `a` register.

Go to line 1 by pressing `:1`

Press `qa` to start recording in `a` register.

Then, search text like `/"\S\+"`.
It will highlight the text.

Then, type `xiconstants.` and then press  <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then `f"`, then `x`.

Type `@a` to replay the register recursively.
Stop recording by pressing `q`.

Hereafter, you can press `@a` once and it will replace everywhere recursively until all such words are changed.